# Angular Nested Controller Data access

Tags: angularjs

I don't know how to access the data from a nested ( child ) controller.

```
    <form ng-controller="TestController as test" ng-submit="submit()">
        <h5>Employee name :</h5>
        <div ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="row-fluid">
            <form class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="name" typeahead="name for name in names | filter:$viewValue" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <h5>Comment : </h5>
        <textarea  ng-model="test.test_content"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

As you can see i have 2 controllers.The main one is a form , the second one is an input box that allows the user to search the name in a list using typeahead.

I want to be able to acces the content of ng-model="name" in my child controller (mainctrl) in my TestController.

I've tried to access it directly with $scope.name but it doesn't work.
I've also tried test.name as the ng-model and it didn't work either.

I'm sending the data of my TestController to my server and would like to send the data ( name ) from my mainCtrl aswell, directly from TestController. So that when my user click submit it send both the name + the test_content in $http.post request.

Anyone know how to do that ?

Thanks

I've found this but it didn't really help.. https://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-models-between-nested-controllers.html

edit:

my search controller

```
          .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.selected = '';
      $http.get('/feedbacks/search.json').
      then(function(response) {
        $scope.succes = " ok "
        $scope.names = response.data;
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }, function(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
          $scope.succes = " error"
      });
  });
```

my form controller :

```
    angular.module('FeedbackTool')
    .controller('TestController',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get('/feedbacks.json').
                        then(function(response) {
                          $scope.succes = " ok "
                          $scope.list = response.data;
                          // this callback will be called asynchronously
                          // when the response is available
                        }, function(response) {
                          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                          // or server returns response with an error status.
                                                        $scope.succes = " error"
                        });
      $scope.submit = function() {
              $http.post('/feedbacks.json', { data:this.test }).
                        then(function(response) {
              $scope.succes = 'sent';
                          // this callback will be called asynchronously
                          // when the response is available
                        }, function(response) {
                          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                          // or server returns response with an error status.
                                            $scope.succes = 'fail';

                        });
          };
    }]);
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code as well?

Answer (score 0):

The parent scope is accessible from within the child scope, but the child scope is not accessible from the parent. Typically the way to deal with this is to assign values from the child scope to properties already defined in the parent. In your case I think you just need to use test.name as the ng-model expression.

Comment: Yeah i already tested that and it's not working. Actually  my form isn't being submitted altogether anymore.. So i guess my best bet is to merge both controller into one so that i don't hve that issue anymore but it's gonna be dirty to look at

Comment: Without the controller code it's hard to tell what the issue is. Before you go to an architecture you don't want, I'd recommend checking out this: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/nestedcontrollers/

Comment: i just update my post with both my controllers. I divideed it into 2 controller just for the sake of clarity i don't really thought there would be issues tbh, thanks for the links that seems helpfull

Comment: Ok i've merged both controller into one ( the test controller ) and it's working now. It's still very ugly tho because on the same controller i basically handle  #index #new #search actions ;//